# Can gcc compile graphics.h or will graphic.h only compile with the borlan turbo c compiler

Tags: c, bgi

I see everyone recommends just using openGL and some others but I don't wanna. I just want to know if graphic.h will only compile in turbo c and not with gcc, Thanks

Comment: I believe it's a matter of DOS, not compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get `graphics.h` compiled (as `#include`d part of some sources), but the linking (coming after the compilation) will fail, as gcc's linker (ld) would not link the compilation's result against the library (`graphics.lib`) implementing what `graphics.h` prototyped.

Comment: Background reading for the OP: [C track: compiling C programs](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/c/mike/misc/compiling_c.html)

Answer (score 2):

Of course you could compile graphics.h with `gcc` but you have to follow certain steps.

1. Get the files `graphics.h` from [graphics](http://nikhilbhardwaj.in/resources/graphics/graphics.h) and `libbgi.a` from [library](http://nikhilbhardwaj.in/resources/graphics/libbgi.a).
2. Copy the `graphics.h` file to the `include` directory of your gcc compiler.
3. Copy the `libbgi.a` file to the `lib` directory of your gcc compiler.
4. Afterwards execute the code:

   `C:\>gcc your_filename.c -lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32`

   Also if you are executing a c++ program use `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could compile graphics.h with gcc but you have to follow certain steps.

1. Get the files graphics.h and libbgi.a from  [here](https://github.com/SagarGaniga/Graphics-Library/tree/master) and follow instructions.
2. Copy the graphics.h file to the include directory of your gcc compiler.
3. Copy the libbgi.a file to the lib directory of your gcc compiler.
4. Afterwards execute the code:
   C:>gcc your_filename.c -lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32

   Also if you are executing a C++ program use g++ instead of gcc.